# installing PHP with LAMP server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, localhost

I am trying to install LAMP on my Ubuntu 12.04, from the method shown in this [link](http://www.linuxcandy.com/2011/11/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-1110.html). After running the following code

```
 sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2
```

I should have php installed, but when i type "localhost/info.php" it does not show the PHP window that it is supposed to show, instead the file gets downloaded in the Downloads folder

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Also is your mod-php enabled?

Comment: you need to movie "php.info" file to /var/www/html . In previous versions of apache there used to be no folder as "html" . "It works" page (localhost) was placed in /var/www instead of /var/www/html. :)

Comment: Try using Tasksel http://stackoverflow.com/a/39689436/1153703

Answer (score 2):

Restart the apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I would recommend you to install the packages in a different order:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server
```

I mean , install first apache so when php is installed then will automatically enable the mod_php apache module. But because you installed the php5 package first may be the mod_php is not yet enabled. Just double check that.