# How to install and configure LAMP on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

Could somebody please tell me how to install and configure LAMP on ubuntu 12.04 ? Is there a package similar to WAMP Server that is all-in-one ? I have tried to install from command line ,PHP,MySQL work but apache gives me this after sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.

And I think probably I did something wrong when installing !

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow tutorial from below link to setup LAMP on your Ubuntu 12,

http://technarco.com/ubuntu-linux/how-install-lamp-ubuntu-12

Enjoy, :)

Answer (score 2):

From [this tutorial](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu),

Run this commands in Ubuntu Terminal-

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

For Checking-

```
php -r 'echo "\n\nYour PHP installation is working fine.\n\n\n";'
```

If u get-

**Your PHP installation is working fine.**

Then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you need to stop other process using this port.
In some of cases it is nginx. you can stop it

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install lamp server using Tasksel (Tasksel is a Debian/Ubuntu tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system. This program is used during the installation process, but users can also use tasksel at any time)

check this post http://wiki.workassis.com/ubuntu-install-lamp-using-tasksel/

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : Open Terminal & Update Your System

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Step-2 : Install Apache Server

```
$ sudo apt install apache2
```

Step-3 : Enable Firewall to allow Apache requests

```
$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"
```

Step-4 : Install MySQL

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Step-5 : Install PHP & Php-Mysql, Php-Apache libraries

```
$ sudo apt install php php-mysql libapache2-mod-php
```

Step-6 : Install PhpMyAdmin & Required Libraries

```
$ sudo apt install php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-curl php-json
$ sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Step-7 : Restart Apache & update the system

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$ sudo apt update
```

Step-8 : Set Root User Password

```
$ sudo mysql
$ mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
$ mysql> exit
```

Step-9 : Restart Apache & MySQL

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Step-10 : Congrats! You have successfully installed LAMP Stack.
To verify Apache, Go to [http://localhost](http://localhost/)
To verify PhpMyAdmin, Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin